# My child form is not visible when I show it from MDI Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mdi

I have two forms : 1 MDI form and 1 Child form

Whene I show (Form.show()) my Child Form on my MDI Form, the Child Form is not visible. What is the problem ?

My code is :

```vb
'My MDI Form code
Private Sub GestionnaireDesTâchesToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GestionnaireDesTâchesToolStripMenuItem.Click
    TaskMGR.Show()
End Sub

'My Child form code
Private Sub TaskMGR_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.MdiParent = Form1
    Me.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Code like yours works perfectly fine for me. That said, there are a couple of oddities. Firstly, you generally set the `MdiParent` in the parent form before calling `Show`. Doing it in the child is bad practice. Also, setting `Visible` to `True` at the end of the `Load` event handler is pointless as that's what happens when that event handler completes anyway. Make those changes and try again. If it still doesn't, try a new test project with the bare minimum of functionality to test that specifically. You should always do that before posting here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify `Form1` to be an MDIContainer?

If so, did you set `Form2`s location to be outside the visible range?